# Well Trained Classifier Does not Perform Well in Same Source of Dataset

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, classification, training-data

I am doing a tweet classification project, and the task now is to determine whether a tweet is, for instance, road traffic-related or not.

I have collected a huge number of tweets(over 1 million). To train a classifier, I first use keywords(such as crash, accident, road, etc.) to get some candidate traffic-related tweets. Then I manually review these tweets and check whether these tweets are traffic-related or not. I also construct another dataset which are not traffic-related. Finally, I get 1000 traffic-related tweets and 2000 not traffic-related tweets.

Then I use the CNN-LSTM model based on pre-trained word embedding to classify the tweets. The overall structure of the model is:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import binary_accuracy, binary_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, Reshape, Input
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM

def conv2d_lstm_weibo(kernel_height, dropout_rate):
    # Get the input information - tweet only
    tweet_input = Input(shape=(60, 300, 1), name='tweet_input')

    # Create the convolutional layer and lstm layer
    conv2d = Conv2D(filters=100, kernel_size=(kernel_height, 300), padding='valid',
                    activation='relu', use_bias=True, name='conv_1')(tweet_input)
    reshaped_conv2d = Reshape((conv2d.shape[1], 100), name='reshape_1')(conv2d)
    conv_drop = Dropout(dropout_rate, name='dropout_1')(reshaped_conv2d)
    lstm = LSTM(100, return_state=False, activation='tanh',
                recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', name='lstm_1')(conv_drop)
    lstm_drop = Dropout(dropout_rate, name='dropout_2')(lstm)
    dense_1 = Dense(100, activation='relu', name='dense_1')(lstm_drop)
    output = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='output_dense')(dense_1)
    # Build the model
    model = Model(inputs=tweet_input, outputs=output)
    return model
```

The dimension of the pre-trained word vector is `(300,1)`. The training data, validation data, and test data account for 60%, 20%, and 20% of the labeled data. I use Adam optimizer with a learning rate of 0.001. Actually, the model performs quite well, reaching a 0.99 F1 score on the test data. The confusion matrix about the performance of the model on the test data is:

```
[[384   3]
 [  2 223]]
```

However, when I use the trained classifier to make the prediction on all the tweets I have collected. **The performance is really bad**. I manually check the tweet which is labeled by `traffic_related` by the classifier, and I find that most of the tweets are not traffic-related at all.

I am wondering which part I did is wrong. Any suggestions and insights are very appreciated!